# Getting IndexError when iterating changeable number of table rows

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping **an ever changing number of rows in a table** on a website using BeautifulSoup 4.4. In the code below there are four tables - but it changes constantly from day to day.

**Main question**:

- How do I get ridd of the IndexError message?

Status: I'm trying to set the number of iterable items as maximum iterations (but it's not solving the actual problem).

**Sub question**:

- I'm planning on appending the output to a file - does the index error
  of iterating this table affect the data output or other processes connected to the iteration in any way? (I still want to avoid the error message
  regardless).

**IndexError message:**
`item_name = strengths.findAll('tr')[x].findAll('td')[0].get_text()
IndexError: list index out of range`

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="iconize iconize-icon-left">
                <span class="incidents-icon" title="Description"></span>
                Heinz 57 ketchup 
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">
            <span class="level">Popular</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr> # same structure as the tr above
<tr> # same structure as the tr above
<tr> # same structure as the tr above
</tbody>
```

My code so far:

```
strengths = strengths_div.table.tbody

output = []

iter_length = len(list(strengths)) # Finding out the number of iterable elements

x = 0 # counter 

for tr in strengths:
    while x <= int(iter_length):  

    item_name = strengths.findAll('tr')[x].findAll('td')[0].get_text()
    strength_value = strengths.findAll('tr')[x].findAll('td')[1].get_text()
    item_name = item_name.strip()
    strength_value = strength_value.strip()

    x = x + 1
```

Comment: Is this the complete code? Where is the part where you append the output to the list? Also, there is an indentation problem in the while loop.

Comment: @RenaeLider: This is only the section of my code concerning the iteration. I intentionally left out the rest (also I haven't written the output append code yet - but still I would like to know if the IndexError could affect the data correctness).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you're going to use an index, you don't want to use x = len(iterable), because an iterable of length n will not have an index n. The greatest index is n - 1, so the while loop line should start like this: `while x < int(iter_length):`. Also, I don't understand the purpose of your outer `for` loop, since you're not using `tr` anywhere in the loop that I can see.

One good way to avoid index errors is to loop over the items in an iterable instead of over its indexes. It generally makes the code neater and easier to read, too. Here's what I would do:

```
for items in strengths.findAll('tr'):

    item_name = items.findAll('td')[0].get_text()
    strength_value = items.findAll('td')[1].get_text()
    item_name = item_name.strip()
    strength_value = strength_value.strip()
```

Comment: +1 Good point. Also, while keeping count of any sequence/container/iterable, doing `x += 1` is much expensive than making the list and doing `len(mylist)`.

Comment: @AmyTeegarden: Thanks for your answer! It makes sense what you're saying about the length of n. I have altered the while loop as per your instructions. Concerning the outer for loop - I'm not an expert, but I thought I was using 'tr' inside the loop, in my navigation (beautifulsoup4). If you have a better way of iterating the table rows, I'm all ears (eyes) ;)

Comment: @RenaeLider: Thanks for the comment. Could you perhaps elaborate a bit (simple example)? I'm a python newbie ...

Comment: @LoenstruPython: I'm not familiar with Beautifulsoup, I'm afraid, but I don't see `tr` anywhere in the loop, just `'tr'`, which is totally different from Python's point of view. (And if you are using `tr` somewhere, you might want to rename it to avoid confusion.)

Comment: @AmyTeegarden: Allrighty - clearly my bad. I just assumed since I didn't get any error, that it was running correctly. Going to check up on the for loops ;-) Thanks!

Comment: @AmyTeegarden - btw. I have later learned, that I should put either a "while - else" or "try - except" statement inside the code to handle the exception.